# convert javascript (regex) function to php

Tags: php, javascript, regex, function

When an key is pressed in an input I call this on its value

`.trim().replace(/ /g, '.').replace(/[^\w .-]/gi, '').toLowerCase();`

what I want to do is, when the value is submitted to the server I want to do a function that will take the value, fun the php version of this function over it, and if the new string is different to the original string return false, else return true.

So, What is the php equivelent of the above line of code?

obviously I can use `strtolower(str_replace(' ', '.', trim($value)))`

which means I just need to equivelent of `.replace(/[^\w .-]/gi, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/[^\w .-]/', '', $subject);
```

Notes: The global flag g is not needed in php. Flag i is not necessary for \w.

And as a side note: You don't actually need the space in the character class because you removed spaces already.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be preg_replace(pattern, replacement)?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @Hailwood: If you add delimiters, yes. Googling for `php regular expression` revealed: http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html I suggest to have a look at it.

Comment: It should. Here's the syntax rerefence for PCRE (used in preg_ functions): http://www.regextester.com/pregsyntax.html

Comment: Like Felix said, you need to note it as a string literal (JavaScript has Regex literals; PHP does not), so just wrap it around with ' quotes.

Answer (score 1):

looks like your found `strtolower` and `trim` on your own. to replace something using a regular expression, simply use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (or [preg_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) if the replacement should be a regular expression, too).

depending on wich version of php you're using, theres also [ereg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php), but you shouldn't rely on that as it's deprecated. if possible, use preg_replace/preg_filter.